# Rails API : How to determine which action and route was fired which lead to invoking a particular Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have multiple engines in my `Rails API` only application. Each having its own routes and set of controllers.

How can i determine what was the route and the action responsible for triggering the method/action in a controller ?

For more details regarding the question let me know.

NOTE : I want to determine it programatically inside the controller itself and not from outside the application.

Comment: Isnt it clear from routes and namespaces? You can guess it by url or track it down in webserver logs

Comment: What do you mean by _"the route and the action"_ – its path and HTTP verb? Could you give an example?

Comment: We know routes which are defines in the config maps to controllers and its functions , right ? I want to determine in the controller itself which route invoked the function(action) and its verb too if its possible.

Comment: colud you please describe exact problem? it sounds like you've lost control over your application and now desperately trying regain it by identifying which controller does what job. i guess you've screwed up whole application logic -)) have a look up to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters

it might help you

Comment: Its just a poc that i am trying to do here . No matter good or bad practices here , i was just trying to figure out whether the object of the application controller has present route information or not ? What will i achieve with this ? Custom Service level authorization which run only via metadata but thats a whole different story. Step by Step. Thanks for your concern though

Answer (score 0):

Inside your project directory do

```
 rake routes
```

This will fetch all the routes in the application.

```
   Prefix      Verb    URI Pattern                  Controller#Action  Named Helper

   articles     GET    /articles(.:format)           articles#index   articles_path or articles_url
```

**example:** The URI '/articles' will look for index action of ArticlesController.

Comment: I want to determine it programatically inside the controller itself and not from outside the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rake routes` to display all routes your app recognizes. Use `grep` to filter by controller or action name.

```
rake routes | grep users
```

Where `users` is just an example controller name.

Comment: I want to determine it programatically inside the controller itself and not from outside the application.

Comment: What do you expect as a result, or what do you mean by "which route". Do you want the line number in `routes.rb` for example?